# How to stop cPanel Upgrades over-writing my custom exim.conf file

Tags: cpanel, exim

Our exim.conf file is still getting overwritten by cpanel updates

http://serversitters.com/cpanel-overwrites-config-files.html suggests adding file to /etc/cpanelsync.exclude
We tried this and it doesnt work. File is still being overwritten.

Old posts on forums.cpanel.net say you cant stop it being overwritten, but I was hoping someone else had come up with a solution.

cpanel has suggested "You should be able to use the /scripts/prebuildeximconf and /scripts/postbuildeximconf hook scripts to preserve your exim.conf modifications across updates." but we do not have these files.

What I specifically need to do is add primarydomain = "ourdomain.com" with is removed with every update. How can I get this to be added back into the file automatically after cpanel update?

Comment: I need an answer, so please dont vote down without giving a reason why there is a problem with the question

Comment: Any update on if using the `cpanelsync.exclude` file works as expected now?

Comment: Update: It does not seem to work as expected. The file continues to be overwritten. The documentation does say that ["you cannot use the `cpanelsync.exclude` file to prevent modifications to configuration files"](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/The+cpanelsync.exclude+File). So, maybe this approach is a lost cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to CPanel, you can't stop it being updated.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you please give a try with file attributes options. Setup the attributes to your exim configuration file so that it will not update in upcp process.

Comment: I set to 600 but its owned by root, so thats not going to make it readonly.
How do I make the file not writable by root, but be able to edit and remove the file in the future if I need to?

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes to file.

Use the below command to change the attributes of file /etc/exim.conf

**Step 1**
Check the current permissions

**root@server2 [~]# ls -lh /etc/exim.conf**

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 67K Jan 19 12:28 /etc//exim.conf

**Step 2**
modify permissions to read only for root also by using chmod command

**root@server2 [/etc]# chmod 444 exim.conf**

**Step 3**
Check the modifications

**root@server2 [/etc]# ls -l exim.conf**

-r--r--r-- 1 root root 68318 Jan 19 12:28 exim.conf

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Now use the attributes so that c-panel updates can not put any affect to exim.conf

**Step 4
root@server2 [/etc]# chattr +ia exim.conf**

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

chattr +i :
A file is set with ‘i‘ attribute, cannot be modified    (immutable). Means no renaming, no symbolic link creation, no execution, no writable, only superuser can unset the attribute.

chattr +a :
A file is set with ‘i‘ attribute, cannot be modified (immutable). Means no renaming, no symbolic link creation, no execution, no writable, only superuser can unset the attribute.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Step 5**
Check the attributes

**root@server2 [/etc]# lsattr exim.conf**

----ia-A-----e- exim.conf

**Step 6**

When you want to modify the file again change attributes of file.

**root@server2 [/etc]# chattr -ia exim.conf** and change permissions back to 644.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

This will sort out the C-Panel automatic update problem.